# Screen record in application with SDK under 21

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

I'm trying to make my app have a feature: record itself and write to external store and import to Youtube. I used MediaProjection with API 21+, it's done. 
But if i want to record in lower devices (i mean device with SDK 20 or lower), how is possile? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain the technical implementation, but I know you require your device to be rooted and access it at a system level rather than using the android framework.

Comment: Thank you sir, not pretty clear but i still vote for you. Thanks :D